# Setting up subdomains for ubuntu server 14.04?

Tags: server

I have spent the past 5 or so days googling and asking on various IRC channels, but I can't seem to find an answer. Before I ask the question, I'll give what information I think is relevant, since I'm not quite sure what is needed. If any more information is required, please let me know. Anyways, I bought a vps through [DemonVPS](http://demonvps.com) and a domain name (for the sake of clarity, lets call it example.io) through [godaddy](http://godaddy.com). I pointed the A file (of example.io) at my vps' IP, and set the rDNS of my vps to example.io, and have apache all setup on my vps. So basically, I have a fully functional website. Now, I want to setup the following things on my vps:

- A Teamspeak3 server
- An IRC Server (mostly for testing purposes of an ircd)
- An IRC Bouncer (ZNC in this case)

I can do all of these quite easily, but the issue is connecting to them. Each of them I have to connect to using "example.io", and I want each to have a unique subdomain (ie ts3.example.io, irc.example.io, and ichat.example.io respectively) that they can only connect to through that. I have scoured the internet, but every tutorial I found was either how to setup just the server, or how to setup subdomains in general, and as to that I have gotten mixed answers about needing apache or not. Any help in setting up subdomains for each of these applications would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not need apache on server for subdomains. You need apache only for web. Enough is to create record on dns server, probably on godaddy.

`ichat.example.io A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

type of record is A

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is ip of your server

When anybody will to go on your irc server practical will connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:irc_port.